# Apply css properties on only first tr of parent table (using only css classes, no usage of id's)

Tags: html, css, html-table

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="someclass">
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>.....</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The code snippet above here I want to style first tr of parent table with someclass like:

```
.someclass tr td{
.......
......
}
```

but it is getting applied to inner table also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I liked Gosi's answer about applying 'first-of-type' to your css. But then I read the comments and realised, so thought I'd follow up with this:

Try:

```
.someclass tr:first-of-type {
background: blue;
}
```

As per Gosi's answer, then also add this:

```
.someclass tr table tr:first-of-type {
background: none;
}
```

Comment: .someclass tr table tbody>tr :first-of-type {.....}     this gets working

Comment: Yeah something like that, and then like in my answer, overwrite the styles for the deeper trs later in your css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following css for this

```
.someclass > tr {
    // your css here
}
```

Or

```
.someclass > tr:first-child {
    // your css here
}
```

or

```
.someclass tr:first-of-type {
    // your css here
}
```

Comment: it gets applied to inner table tr also and i want only on parent table tr